# How to sort HashMap based off the order they were parsed in using Java?

Tags: java

I have a HashMap which is made up of parsed values from a textfile. Whenever I extract the contents from this HashMap, they come out in abc order. How do I keep the order that they were parsed, basically in a FIFO order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`LinkedHashMap`,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which can preserve insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` itself is not capable of preserving the order information. Have a look at other implementations, the standard library contains [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) for example.